# Where to.... gem install foundation?

Tags: installation, zurb-foundation

Trying to evolve my workflow from 960.gs to a modern framework.

I’m just getting started with Foundation5/SaSS. I understand that installing Bower is a one time global installation, but what about installing Foundation (gem install foundation)? Should that be installed in a specific folder: if so which folder?

Working on OS X, my files are kept in: 
~/Sites/_CLIENT/_PROJECT/_ITERATION
(multiple clients, projects & iterations)

Apologies if this is a dumb question… just want to avoid installing difficult to remove items in the wrong places

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I am unfamiliar with SASS and the gem install of foundation, this answer relates to the bower install only.  From looking at the docs, it looks like the 'gem install foundation' command installs a foundation executable globally, but I'm not sure, hopefully someone experienced in this will chime in.*

If you are using Bower for the rest of your dependency management (I find it much easier to manage when I'm using a single route to get my dependencies).

Inside the project folder, run:

> bower install zurb/bower-foundation --save

Bower is not for global installs, it just downloads a given set of dependencies and places them in a "bower_components" folder within your current project folder.  It's purpose is to keep you from having to hunt down the current links for a given dependency, and allow easy updates.

The:

> --save

argument, saves this dependency in a "bower.json" file, which helps you keep track of dependencies/versions.  In the future, if you move this project, or you accidentally delete a folder, and you have properly saved all dependencies to the bower.json file, you can run

> bower install

and all dependencies will be downloaded and installed to the correct folders automatically.